# Significance of bronze rating

Tags: starcraft-2

I wanted to know what the significance of the word and term "bronze" means to someone who plays as a "terrin/terran"? Is bronze a good thing for this player? Can someone please explain….THANK YOU (sorry for the improper use of any terms. I'm not really good with this game, but would like to know more)

Answer (score 4):

All Starcraft II players who played at least 5 ranked games are placed in a *league*. A league is a sort of a translation of the skill of the player. 7 leagues exist in Starcraft II: *(from lowest to highest)*

- **Bronze:** it's for the beginners. It regroups around 8.55% of the players.
- **Silver:** for beginners who level up :) ~27.88%.
- **Gold:** intermediate level, regroup most of the players in SC2. ~38%.
- **Platinium:** for players who begin to have nice skills. ~15.28%.
- **Diamond:** for players who play a lot. ~8.73%.
- **Master:** for players with huge skills, you can find good amateurs and semi-professional players there. ~1.26%.
- **Grand Master:** highest league, for semi-pro or professionnel. It is limited to 200 players for each server (Europe, North America, Korea and South-East Asia). ~0.30%.

You can find a good league description in [**Liquipedia**](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues) and you can find some good statistics about league repartition, by regions, on [**sc2ranks**](http://www.sc2ranks.com/stats/league).

Answer (score 2):

In SC2, players are assigned to certain leagues based on how well they do in matchmaking (competitive games). Bronze is the lowest league, containing about 9% of all players. The term 'bronze' is thus often used in a diminutive way to insult a player's skill.

Source: http://www.sc2ranks.com/stats/league